# Adding Cloud Based database to kotlin app

Tags: database, sqlite, kotlin, cloud

I was recently tasked in creating a quiz game and i did it all fine. i have an sqlite database linked to it but its just a local one. what should i do to make it cloud based? please help im running out of time.I tried using firebase for it but im lost i dont know what to do and the videos does not help.The app consists of like 8 tables nothing to fancy but i want them to be live for everyone to access not just local.
https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: Hi, you have to pick a traditional database., like MySql. You can find online  hundreds of free offers

Answer (score 0):

You could [make a python-based API in AWS Lambda](https://youtu.be/uFsaiEhr1zs) and call the database there instead.